# Extracting main image from posted link/ and from the posted page

Tags: python, django

Game plan is to extract those main images, and display them in a thumbnail in the index page. I'm having so much trouble for this functionality, it seems like there's no example for this functionality in the internet. 
I found three options 
1. beautifulsoup// seems like people use this approach the most but I have no idea how beautifulsoup can find the representative image...also it requires the most work I think. 2. python goose// this looks legit. the documentation says it extracts main image, I guess I need to trust their words. problem is I don't know how to use this in django. 
3. embedly//....maybe wrong choice for the functionality I need. I'm thinking to use python goose for this project. 
My question is how would you approach this problem? and do you know any example or can provide some example I can look at? for extracting image from images user provide to my page I can probably use sorl-thumbnail(right?_) but for posted link....??

Edit1: using python goose, it seems (main)image scraping is very simple. problem is I'm not sure how to use the script to my app, how should I turn that image to right thumbnail and display on my index.html...
Here is my media.py(not sure if it works yet

```
  import json
from goose import Goose

def extract(request):
    url = request.args.get('url')
    g = Goose()
    article = g.extract(url=url)
    resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}
    return json.dumps(resposne)
```

source: https://blog.openshift.com/day-16-goose-extractor-an-article-extractor-that-just-works/
the blog example is using flask, I tried to make the script for people using django

Edit 2: Ok, here is my approach. I really think this is right, but unfortunately it doesn't give me anything. no error or no image but the python syntax is right....if there's anyone why it's not working please let me know

Models.py

class Post(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

```
def extract(request, url):
    url = requests.POST.get('url')
    g = Goose()
    article = g.extract(url=url)
    resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}
    return json.dumps(resposne)
```

Index.html

```
{% if posts %}
    {% for post in posts %}
      {{ post.extract}}
{%endfor%}
{%endif%}
```

Answer (score 4):

BeautifulSoup would be the way to go for this, and is actually remarkably easy.

To begin, an image in HTML looks like this:

```
<img src="http://www.url.to/image.png"></img>
```

We can use BeautifulSoup  to extract all `img` tags and then find the `src` of the `img` tag. This is achieved as shown below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #Import stuff
import requests

r  = requests.get("http://www.site-to-extract.com/") #Download website source

data = r.text  #Get the website source as text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data) #Setup a "soup" which BeautifulSoup can search

links = []

for link in soup.find_all('img'):  #Cycle through all 'img' tags
    imgSrc = link.get('src')   #Extract the 'src' from those tags
    links.append(imgSrc)    #Append the source to 'links'

print(links)  #Print 'links'
```

I don't know how you plan on deciding which image to use as thumbnail, but you can then through the list of URL's and extract the one you want.

**Update**

I know you said dJango, but I would highly recommend Flask. It's a lot simpler, yet still very functional.

I wrote this, which simply displays the 1st image of whatever webpage you give it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #Import stuff
import requests
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

def getImages(url):
    r  = requests.get(url) #Download website source

    data = r.text  #Get the website source as text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data) #Setup a "soup" which BeautifulSoup can search

    links = []

    for link in soup.find_all('img'):  #Cycle through all 'img' tags
        imgSrc = link.get('src')   #Extract the 'src' from those tags
        links.append(imgSrc)    #Append the source to 'links'

    return links  #Return 'links'

@app.route('/<site>')
def page(site):
    image = getImages("http://" + site)[0] #Here I find the 1st image on the page
    if image[0] == "/":
        image = "http://" + site + image  #This creates a URL for the image
    return "<img src=%s></img>" % image  #Return the image in an HTML "img" tag

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")  #Run the Flask webserver
```

This hosts a web server on http://localhost:5000/

To input a site, do http://localhost:5000/yoursitehere, for example http://localhost:5000/www.google.com

Comment: I was just working on this, I have decided to use python goose and was having problem implementing the script to my index.html...I will edit what I did, I would be really appreciated if you can take a look at it.

Comment: And doesn't your code print all the images then? not just one main image? that's why I switched to python goose

Comment: @haloyoba What do you mean by "main image?" Like, the largest image on a page, or an image of what the page actually looks like when loaded?

Comment: yes the image that represents the article, probabaly the biggest image

Comment: @haloyoba - Ok, so all you need to do is go through the list of image URL's and decide which one is suitable, possibly by checking the dimensions of it. I don't really know how you would do this though.

Comment: yeah that's why I'm going with goose

Comment: Ah. Ok. I updated my answer with an app that uses BeautifulSoup, but you can just replace the `getImage()` function with yours.

Comment: hmm I see it's in flask, can you convert them to django?I know a great example for flask already. In my opinion this is better approach, https://blog.openshift.com/day-16-goose-extractor-an-article-extractor-that-just-works/

Comment: @haloyoba I'm not really experienced in dJango, however I have used it. I don't know how you would convert this over.

Comment: I think I kinda figured it out, I will post it up there anyone looking for this feature

Comment: Ok, great! Good luck!